# Edit the New item URL in SharePoint 2010 ribbon

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

We have a custom web part to add new item to SharePoint 2010 list. I want to open the page on which i have added the web part on the click of new item from SharePoint ribbon. I don not want to create a custom list definition just for the sake of modifying the new item URL of ribbon. Is there any other workaround to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create New/Edit form for list using Sharepoint Designer and insert your web part to this page. Then set this form as default and all ribbon buttons and other menu items wich go to creation form will lead you to the your page by default.

In SPD go to List -> Your list -> Create New  List Form -> Check "New item form" radio.

Comment: are you suggesting to add the .webpart file code on the newitem form created in SP designer

Comment: Yes, try to go this way